# Simple string hashing function

Tags: string, delphi, hash

I'm trying to hash a string into an integer for placing it in an array. However I do not know all too much about hashing functions, and that's why my current method is just adding all the ASCII numbers of the characters together and taking it mod the array size.

Are there any simple faster/better methods?

Comment: Are you trying to make a hash table?

Comment: Duplicate of [half of that](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=string+hash+function).

Comment: I am using Delphi at the moment

Comment: Hal, as you can see, hashes are poorly understood and often an excuse for a nerd fight.

Comment: Is there any community wiki on hash functions? If not, probably it makes sense to start one, with information structured by input types, performance and language implementations.

Answer (score 13):

The [FNV-1a hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler_Noll_Vo_hash) is quick and easy to implement.

Comment: It's quick, easy and terrible. Its avalanche characteristics are unacceptable. If you must use an FNV variant, FNV-1a is much, much better in this regard. Or, better yet, don't use FNV at all. There are so many better alternatives that this one is a waste of time.

Comment: +1. FNV Wikipedia entry beats that one of the Jenkins. And language agnostic.

Comment: @Dummy: Only because they omitted the avalanche results. It turns out that FNV-1a doesn't suck, but FNV does. For that matter, Jenkins' lookup3 is ok, whereas his one-at-a-time sucks.

Comment: @Greg: I doubt you care about your rep score any more than I do, but if you edit your answer to specify FNV-1a, then I'l be glad to remove the downvote. I still don't like this FNV variant, but at least it's not terrible.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: That's fair, changed the link.

Comment: Done. If I'm reading the chart at http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions right, it looks like FNV-1a is optimized for longer inputs, so it would not do well with short strings.

Comment: [Comparing FNV-1, FNV-1a, DJB2, DJB2a, SDBM, CRC32](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/what-hashing-algorithm-is-good-for-uniqueness-and-speed/145633#145633). Of those **FNV-1a** is the best.

Comment: @IanBoyd That was very helpful. I'm glad you added Murmur2 and I'm not surprised that it did so well, but I'm wondering if you've tried Murmur3.

Comment: @StevenSudit It's a coincidence that you mention it. i've been looking at it for the past hour. i've translated it into Delphi, but there's no test vectors out there, so i can't be sure i have it right (it's very endian sensitive; and who knows what order the original C++ is doing things in).

Comment: @IanBoyd I suspect you can find sample vectors, or just ask the author.

Comment: @StevenSudit There's been an open issue on the project homepage since 2009 asking for test vectors.

Comment: @StevenSudit No, but [you're free to harass him if you like](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/issues/detail?id=6).

Comment: @IanBoyd Ok, I dropped him a note, using our employer emails.

Comment: @StevenSudit i would't worry about it too much. i'm confident my implementation is correct. But even if it's not, the MurmurHash3 performance is lower than that of MurmurHash2. i even went down to `asm`, calling `rol` instruction rather than the algorithm's own implementation of "rotate". Given that it's slower, and it's lack of test vectors, i've not pursued it further - deciding on `MurmurHash2` is *"the best for my hash table purposes"*.

Comment: @IanBoyd Austin responded on smhasher with: 'SMHasher uses the VerificationTest function to check if a hash function is correctly implemented - it doesn't rely on correct capitalization or punctuation of "The quick brown fox..." and catches more implementation errors than a single test vector can. I'll make a note on the front page to point it out.'

Comment: @IanBoyd On a side note, depending on the compiler, you can get C/C++ to emit a ROL instruction for you without messing with assembler directly.

Comment: I guess you tested a pascal slow version of crc32.
crc32 could be fast, faster than most others, if used with 8KB of lookup tables and asm, and even much faster than alternative if your CPU has SSE4.2 hardware instructions of it. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/05/25/New-crc32c%28%29-function-using-optimized-asm-and-SSE-4.2-instruction
About hash distribution, crc32 is very good - see https://www.delphitools.info/2014/08/25/string-hashing-shootout/
You may correct your answer about crc32.

Answer (score 4):

See http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions for a very good panel of hashing functions.

In Delphi implementation, here are several versions:

The first coming to mind is the one used in `TStringHash.HashOf` method from official `IniFiles.pas` unit. Including a  faster asm version:

```
function HashOf(P: PByteArray; Len: integer): cardinal;
// algorithm from IniFiles.TStringHash.HashOf
{$ifdef PUREPASCAL}
var I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 1 to Len do
    Result := ((Result shl 2) or (Result shr (SizeOf(Result)*8-2))) xor P[I];
end;
{$else}
asm // faster asm version by Synopse
    or edx,edx
    jz @z
    push ebx
    mov ebx,edx     // ebx = length(Key)
    mov edx,eax     // edx = Text
    xor eax,eax     // eax = Result
    xor ecx,ecx     // ecx = Result shl 2 = 0
@1: shr eax,$1e     // eax = Result shr (SizeOf(Result) * 8 - 2))
    or ecx,eax      // ecx = ((Result shl 2) or (Result shr (SizeOf(Result)*8-2)))
    movzx eax,byte ptr [edx] // eax = ord(Key[i])
    inc edx
    xor eax,ecx     // eax = () xor ord(Key[i])
    dec ebx
    lea ecx,[eax*4] // ecx = Result shl 2
    jnz @1
    pop ebx
@z:
end;
{$endif}
```

The classic Kernighan & Ritchie hash from "The C programming Language", 3rd edition - not the best, but simple and efficient code.

```
function kr32(crc: cardinal; buf: PAnsiChar; len: cardinal): cardinal;
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to len-1 do
    crc := ord(buf[i])+crc*31;
  result := crc;
end;
```

The fast "Adler" CRC as implemented in zlib - optimized asm version [here](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrypto.pas):

```
function Adler32Pas(Adler: cardinal; p: pointer; Count: Integer): cardinal;
var s1, s2: cardinal;
    i, n: integer;
begin
  s1 := LongRec(Adler).Lo;
  s2 := LongRec(Adler).Hi;
  while Count>0 do begin
    if Count<5552 then
      n := Count else
      n := 5552;
    for i := 1 to n do begin
      inc(s1,pByte(p)^);
      inc(cardinal(p));
      inc(s2,s1);
    end;
    s1 := s1 mod 65521;
    s2 := s2 mod 65521;
    dec(Count,n);
  end;
  result := word(s1)+cardinal(word(s2)) shl 16;
end;
```

My own faster variant - not re-entrant, but faster since it will read by DWORDs - and an even faster [asm version here](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCommons.pas):

```
function Hash32(Data: pointer; Len: integer): cardinal;
function SubHash(P: PCardinalArray; L: integer): cardinal;
{$ifdef HASINLINE}inline;{$endif}
var s1,s2: cardinal;
    i: PtrInt;
const Mask: array[0..3] of cardinal = (0,$ff,$ffff,$ffffff);
begin
  if P<>nil then begin
    s1 := 0;
    s2 := 0;
    for i := 1 to L shr 4 do begin // 16 bytes (4 DWORD) by loop - aligned read
      inc(s1,P^[0]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[1]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[2]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(s1,P^[3]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(PtrUInt(P),16);
    end;
    for i := 1 to (L shr 2)and 3 do begin // 4 bytes (DWORD) by loop
      inc(s1,P^[0]);
      inc(s2,s1);
      inc(PtrUInt(P),4);
    end;
    inc(s1,P^[0] and Mask[L and 3]);      // remaining 0..3 bytes
    inc(s2,s1);
    result := s1 xor (s2 shl 16);
  end else
    result := 0;
end;
begin // use a sub function for better code generation under Delphi
  result := SubHash(Data,Len);
end;
```

The classic CRC32 version - you can find a very [optimized asm version (using 8 tables) here](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynZip.pas):

```
function UpdateCrc32(aCRC32: cardinal; inBuf: pointer; inLen: integer) : cardinal;
var i: integer;
begin
  result := aCRC32;
  // if we used a dynamic table, we assume we want shorter code size
  for i := 1 to inLen do begin
    result := crc32Tab[byte(result xor pByte(inBuf)^)] xor (result shr 8);
    inc(cardinal(inBuf));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Delphi 2009 and up also provides Jenkins Hash (used to hash dictionary entries) in [Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/de/Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash)

Comment: About a comparison of hash functions, take a look at http://www.delphitools.info/2014/08/25/string-hashing-shootout/
In short: crc32 is the best balance between performance and collisions, kr32 has a lot of collisions, and BobJenkinsHash is dead slow.

Answer (score 3):

As Dummy00001 pointed out, this has been asked and answered before. Take a look at [Best algorithm for hashing number values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359654/best-algorithm-for-hashing-number-values), particularly the suggestion of using MurmurHash.

I'd recommend MurmurHash because:

1. It's very fast.
2. Its distribution and avalanche characteristics are excellent for a non-cryptographic hash.
3. Its worst-case behavior is still pretty good.

I've used it. It doesn't suck.

*edit*

There was a lot of discussion about how to best port it to Delphi, on https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=13902&tstart=0. The resulting code is available at https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=14879

### Delphi translation

```
function Murmur2(const S: AnsiString; const Seed: LongWord=$9747b28c): LongWord;
var
    h: LongWord;
    len: LongWord;
    k: LongWord;
    data: Integer;
const
    // 'm' and 'r' are mixing constants generated offline.
    // They're not really 'magic', they just happen to work well.
    m = $5bd1e995;
    r = 24;
begin
    len := Length(S);

    //The default seed, $9747b28c, is from the original C library

    // Initialize the hash to a 'random' value
    h := seed xor len;

    // Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash
    data := 1;

    while(len >= 4) do
    begin
        k := PLongWord(@S[data])^;

        k := k*m;
        k := k xor (k shr r);
        k := k* m;

        h := h*m;
        h := h xor k;

        data := data+4;
        len := len-4;
    end;

    {   Handle the last few bytes of the input array
            S: ... $69 $18 $2f
    }
    Assert(len <= 3);
    if len = 3 then
        h := h xor (LongWord(s[data+2]) shl 16);
    if len >= 2 then
        h := h xor (LongWord(s[data+1]) shl 8);
    if len >= 1 then
    begin
        h := h xor (LongWord(s[data]));
        h := h * m;
    end;

    // Do a few final mixes of the hash to ensure the last few
    // bytes are well-incorporated.
    h := h xor (h shr 13);
    h := h * m;
    h := h xor (h shr 15);

    Result := h;
end;
```

Passes all [self-tests from the original C implementation](http://dmy999.com/article/50/murmurhash-2-java-port).

Comment: Any pointers to proof that the hash function doesn't suffer from the avalanche effect you complain elsewhere so much? Murmur uses pretty much the same algorithm, only slightly differently.

Comment: I answered this elsewhere, but I'll repeat it here: http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/avalanche

Comment: Some people might think that, since the source is the canonical site for MurmurHash, it must be suspect. Those people should read more carefully, and follow the link to http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/

Comment: @Steven: regarding the link - 404 errors when trying to look into at the diagrams at the link. Nor you have provided any link to the sample implementation of advertised algorithm. P.S. the second link (~bretm) shows different avalanche diagram for Jenkins and conclusion is also nice: "This hash function by Bob Jenkins should be suitable for general purpose use, either for hash table lookup, basic file fingerprinting, or other non-cryptographic uses." You are very *trustworthy* source of information ;)

Comment: @Dummy: Pay attention: Mulvey’s diagram was for lookup3, not one-at-a-time.

Comment: @Steven: Pay attention, I linked to the Wikipedia article which links to several implementation - and plethora of other useful information. Remove down-vote from my answer, re-edit your own answer into something more up-vote-worthy (don't you know how to post links here?), and I would remove my down-vote.

Comment: A more comprehensive survey of hash functions, focusing on collision-avoidance and speed, can be found at http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions.

Comment: Edit your answer so that it clearly recommends *only* lookup3, and I'll remove the downvote. I will still suggest that lookup3 be avoided, since MurmurHash is at least as good in terms of distribution and avalanche, and yet it's faster.

Comment: It turns out the 404 errors are due to the fact that the author is in the middle of moving the site to http://tanjent.com/doku.php?id=murmurhash

Comment: Besides http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/what-hashing-algorithm-is-good-for-uniqueness-and-speed/145633#145633, I'd like to mention Murmur3.

Comment: As soon [as i find some test vectors :)](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/issues/detail?id=6)

Comment: Isn't there a bug in the above Pascal implementation where it loads the last 3 bytes?  MurmurHash2.cpp uses switch(len), so the Pascal should use Case len of...  If 3 bytes remain, this code will load 3, then load 2, then load 1.

Answer (score 2):

[Jenkins hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function) should help you get started.

> my current method is just adding all the ASCII numbers of the characters together and taking it mod the array size.

You discard important bit of information which is the position of the character in the string. That is a bad idea, since then strings "AB" and "BA" would have same the same hash value.

Instead of simple addition, keeping it primitive, one can use expression like `hash = hash*P1 + str[i]*P2 + P3;` where P*i* are some prime numbers. That's how I do it if I need a hash function quickly. I often use 7, 5 and 3 as the primes, but the numbers should be obviously adjusted (as well as initial value of `hash`) so that the result of hash function is usable to your task.

For more information read [the corresponding (and rather informative) Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_function_algorithms).

Comment: Sure, start there, but then keep moving. As the article you linked to shows, it has pretty awful avalanche characteristics. Just look at all the yellow pixels.

Comment: @Steven: The yellow dots are really few there. And it is definitely better than simple addition. And it is fast and works fine on real world strings. I use it in several places and it definitely improved key distribution.

Comment: I don't deny for a moment that it's better than addition -- I even pointed out the AB/BA problem in a comment to an answer that was deleted. However, there's no reason there should be *any* yellow pixels. Projects like memcachedb use Murmur for a good reason!

Comment: Don't be silly. There would be always yellow pixels - because one still has to apply modulo to the result of the hash function and that would discard more useful bits of information. And murmur doesn't strike to be much different from Jenkins or FNV. Or you haven't even bothered to check how Murmur works? I think you're being over-pedantic here.

Comment: Oh I'm *definitely* pedantic, but I'm also completely right. It's not radically different, but it's designed to avoid this particular flaw. For a good visual comparison, look at http://sites.google.com/site/murmurhash/avalanche

Comment: From the one of the [linked articles](http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/7.html): "This hash function by Bob Jenkins should be suitable for general purpose use, either for hash table lookup, basic file fingerprinting, or other non-cryptographic uses. Both the upper and lower bits are uniformly distributed. The hash function achieves avalanche for every bit combination tested."

Comment: At risk of repeating myself, I'll point out that this comment was about the lookup3 algorithm, whereas the avalanche graphic we were discussing was for the one-at-a-time algorithm. In short, Mulvey is not backing you up on this one.

Comment: side note: Delphi 2009 and up use this funtion to hash dictionary entries - [Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/de/Generics.Defaults.BobJenkinsHash)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried many fast hash functions and chosen this one:

```
function StrHash(const st:string):cardinal; 
 var
  i:integer;
 begin
  result:=0;
  for i:=1 to length(st) do
   result:=result*$20844 xor byte(st[i]);
 end;
```

It is as fast as K&R function (actually even faster) but makes better (more even) distribution.

Answer (score -3):

A very simple method is to just XOR all values. The simplest as far as I know.

Comment: OMG.  a xor a = 0.  So any string with an even number of the same letters...  Anagrams anyone?