# Where can I find a Delphi implementation of Murmur2 for hashing streams?

Tags: delphi, hash, murmurhash

I am looking for Delphi code to use Murmur2 to hash a file stream.  Should support both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [an implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690631/33732) in another question about hashing. It certainly supports 32-bit code. I can't comment on how readily it transfers to 64 bits.

Comment: That code has exact same meaning under 64 bit compiler

Comment: Thank you, I saw that but that is for a string.  I don't know how to translate that into hashing a stream.

Comment: @Daniel Try this: http://pastebin.com/68KEDDp4 It's also worth pointing out that `AnsiString` isn't the best data type for a hash algo. I'd say that `TBytes` would be better. Easy to adapt algo to that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I get "integer overlow" trying to use this function on a stream.  I experimented with changing longword to int64 with the same error.

Comment: Don't do that! Very bad idea! Don't change the code at all. Just disable integer overflow checking for that code. Put the has code in a separate unit and add this right at the top of that unit: `{$OVERFLOWCHECKS OFF}`

Comment: @Daniel Use the unit in this pastebin and you are good to go: http://pastebin.com/Bw5Sfih0

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that works great, thank you!  Please post that as an official answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Please accept Rob's answer. If you want to include my pastebin code as an answer of your own please do. But Rob's is the answer that you should accept.