# Is there any Delphi implementation of MurMurHash3?

Tags: delphi, murmurhash

Is there any Delphi implementation of MurMurHash 3? I tried implementing it myself, but my implementation is actually slower that the [MurMurHash2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690608/simple-string-hashing-function/3690631#3690631). Is it normal?
Is there any other implementation?

This is mine:

```
function MurMur3_32(const S: AnsiString; const Seed: LongWord=$9747b28c): LongWord;
const
  c1 = $cc9e2d51;
  c2 = $1b873593;
  r1 = 15;
  r2 = 13;
  m = 5;
  n = $e6546b64;
var
    hash: LongWord;
    len: LongWord;
    k, k2: LongWord;
    data: Integer;
begin
  Hash := Seed;

    len := Length(S);

    //The default seed, $9747b28c, is from the original C library

    // Initialize the hash to a 'random' value
    hash := seed xor len;

    // Mix 4 bytes at a time into the hash
    data := 1;

    while(len >= 4) do
    begin
        k := PLongWord(@S[data])^;

        k := k*c1;
        k := (k shl r1) or (k shr (32 - r1));
        k := k*c2;


        hash := hash xor k;
        hash := ((hash shl r2) or (hash shr (32 - r2))) * m + n;

        Inc(Data, 4);
        Dec(len, 4);
    end;

    k2 := 0;

    {   Handle the last few bytes of the input array
            S: ... $69 $18 $2f
    }
    Assert(len <= 3);
    if len = 3 then
        k2 := k2 xor (LongWord(s[data+2]) shl 16);
    if len >= 2 then
        k2 := k2 xor (LongWord(s[data+1]) shl 8);
    if len >= 1 then
    begin
        k2 := k2 xor (LongWord(s[data]));
        k2 := k2 * c1;
        k2 := (k2 shl r1) or (k2 shr (32 - r1));
        k2 := k2 * c2;
        hash := hash xor k2;
    end;

    // Do a few final mixes of the hash to ensure the last few
    // bytes are well-incorporated.
    len := Length(S);

    hash := hash xor len;
    hash := hash xor (hash shr 16);
    hash := hash * $85ebca6b;
    hash := hash xor (hash shr 13);
    hash := hash * $c2b2ae35;
    hash := hash xor (hash shr 16);


    Result := hash;

end;
```

Disclaimer: I don't know if `Seed` value is correct.

Comment: This question is probably closeable for off topic and unclear what you ask. My main comment though would be to wonder why you want to store binary data in a string? Use a byte array.

Comment: I made it with strings just to try the implementation... Of couse everyone che adapt it for his needs. I needed to hash strings... What you don't understand about the question?

Comment: I understand the question but it's off topic because you ask for other libraries and unclear (technical term) because you ask a vague "can it be improved upon". Again, why put binary data in a string? What happens if the string undergoes encoding conversions?

Comment: I think the core question is fine: `why is my straightforward implementation slow?`. Of course mixing in other side-questions like `give me other implementations` makesit borderline off-topic. But I don't think that detracts from the core question.

Comment: @Johan That core question is unclear because no timing details are provided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a murmurhash3 implementation in my FastDefaults unit at https://github.com/JBontes/FastCode

Here's the sourcecode for Murmurhash3:

```
{$pointermath on}
function MurmurHash3(const [ref] HashData; Len: integer; Seed: integer = 0): integer;
const
  c1 = $CC9E2D51;
  c2 = $1B873593;
  r1 = 15;
  r2 = 13;
  m = 5;
  n = $E6546B64;
  f1 = $85EBCA6B;
  f2 = $C2B2AE35;
{$IFDEF purepascal}
var
  i, Len2: integer;
  k: cardinal;
  remaining: cardinal;
  Data: PCardinal;
label
  case1, case2, case3, final;
begin
  Result:= Seed;
  Data:= @HashData;
  for i:= 0 to (Len shr 2) - 1 do begin
    k:= Data[i];
    k:= k * c1;
    k:= (k shl r1) or (k shr (32 - r1));
    k:= k * c2;
    Result:= Result xor k;
    Result:= (Result shl r2) or (Result shr (32 - r2));
    Result:= Result * m + n;
  end; {for i}
  Len2:= Len;
  remaining:= 0;
  case Len and $3 of
    1: goto case1;
    2: goto case2;
    3: goto case3;
    else goto final;
  end;
case3:
  dec(Len2);
  inc(remaining, PByte(Data)[Len2] shl 16);
case2:
  dec(Len2);
  inc(remaining, PByte(Data)[Len2] shl 8);
case1:
  dec(Len2);
  inc(remaining, PByte(Data)[Len2]);
  remaining:= remaining * c1;
  remaining:= (remaining shl r1) or (remaining shr (32 - r1));
  remaining:= remaining * c2;
  Result:= Result xor remaining;
final:
  Result:= Result xor Len;

  Result:= Result xor (Result shr 16);
  Result:= Result * f1;
  Result:= Result xor (Result shr 13);
  Result:= Result * f2;
  Result:= Result xor (Result shr 16);
end;
{$ELSE}
{$REGION 'asm'}
{$IFDEF CPUx86}
  asm
    push EBX
    push EDI
    push ESI
    xchg ECX,EDX
    //EAX = data
    //ECX = count in bytes
    //EDX = seed
    mov  ESI,ECX
    shr  ECX,2
    jz @remaining_bytes
  @loop:
    mov  EDI,[EAX]
    imul EDI,EDI,c1
    rol  EDI,r1
    imul EDI,EDI,c2
    xor  EDX,EDI
    rol  EDX,r2
    lea  EDX,[EDX*4+EDX+n]
    lea  EAX,[EAX+4]
    dec  ECX
    jnz @loop
  @remaining_bytes:
    mov  ECX,ESI
    and  ECX,$3
    jz @finalization
    xor  EBX,EBX
    dec  ECX
    mov  BL,byte ptr [EAX+ECX]
    jz @process_remaining
    shl  EBX,8
    dec  ECX
    mov  BL,byte ptr [EAX+ECX]
    jz @process_remaining
    shl  EBX,8
    mov  BL,byte ptr [EAX]
  @process_remaining:
    imul EBX,EBX,c1
    rol  EBX,r1
    imul EBX,EBX,c2
    xor  EDX,EBX
  @finalization:
    xor  EDX,ESI
    mov  EAX,EDX
    shr  EDX,16
    xor  EDX,EAX
    imul EDX,EDX,f1
    mov  EAX,EDX
    shr  EDX,13
    xor  EDX,EAX
    imul EDX,EDX,f2
    mov  EAX,EDX
    shr  EDX,16
    xor  EAX,EDX
    pop  ESI
    pop  EDI
    pop  EBX
end;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF CPUx64}
asm
  push RBX
  push RDI
  push RSI
  mov  RAX,RCX
  mov  RCX,RDX
  mov  RDX,R8
  //RAX = data
  //RCX = count in bytes
  //RDX = seed
  mov  ESI,ECX
  shr  ECX,2
  jz @remaining_bytes
@loop:
  mov  EDI, dword ptr [RAX]
  imul EDI,EDI,c1
  rol  EDI,r1
  imul EDI,EDI,c2
  xor  EDX,EDI
  rol  EDX,r2
  lea  EDX,dword ptr [EDX*4+EDX+n] // *5 + n
  lea  RAX,qword ptr [RAX+4]
  dec  ECX
  jnz @loop
@remaining_bytes:
  mov  ECX,ESI
  and  ECX,$3
  jz @finalization
  xor  RBX,RBX
  dec  ECX
  mov  BL,byte ptr [RAX+RCX]
  jz @process_remaining
  shl  EBX,8
  dec  ECX
  mov  BL,byte ptr [RAX+RCX]
  jz @process_remaining
  shl  EBX,8
  mov  BL,byte ptr [RAX]
@process_remaining:
  imul EBX,EBX,c1
  rol  EBX,r1
  imul EBX,EBX,c2
  xor  EDX,EBX
@finalization:
  xor  EDX,ESI
  mov  EAX,EDX
  shr  EDX,16
  xor  EDX,EAX
  imul EDX,EDX,f1
  mov  EAX,EDX
  shr  EDX,13
  xor  EDX,EAX
  imul EDX,EDX,f2
  mov  EAX,EDX
  shr  EDX,16
  xor  EAX,EDX
  pop  RSI
  pop  RDI
  pop  RBX
end;
{$ENDIF}
{$ENDREGION}
{$ENDIF}
```

The goto's are in place to simulate C's fallthough switch/case statement.
This kind of code is easier to write in asm, which has better register usage than the asm Delphi generates.

**Why is your code slow**
he only place I can see a problem is here:

```
Project42.dpr.54: while(len >= 4) do    //a for loop is faster.
00420E17 83FE04           cmp esi,$04
00420E1A 7242             jb $00420e5e

//This translates into inefficient code
Project42.dpr.56: k := PLongWord(@S[data])^;  
00420E1C 8B0424           mov eax,[esp]
00420E1F 8D4438FF         lea eax,[eax+edi-$01]
00420E23 8B00             mov eax,[eax]
```

Three indirect memory references and the [read is misaligned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)!!
See here for more info: [Purpose of memory alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381244/purpose-of-memory-alignment) *never mind the accepted answer, see the second answer*.
A read of a double word should always happen on a dword boundary.
The `@pointer^` trick makes the compiler to add an extra level of indirection (and an extra round-trip to memory (Oops)).
***Use `{$pointermath on}` and address the pointer as an array.***

**integer != pointer**
Also it's an error to use `integer` to store a pointer.
It will break in X64. ***Use NativeUInt instead.***

The equivalent code in my version translates to:

```
Project42.dpr.128: Data:= @HashData;
00420FCD 89442404         mov [esp+$04],eax
Project42.dpr.129: for i:= 0 to (Len shr 2) - 1 do begin
00420FD1 8B1C24           mov ebx,[esp]
00420FD4 C1EB02           shr ebx,$02
00420FD7 4B               dec ebx
00420FD8 85DB             test ebx,ebx
00420FDA 7C3E             jl $0042101a
00420FDC 43               inc ebx
00420FDD 33D2             xor edx,edx
////------------------------------------------///
Project42.dpr.130: k:= Data[i];
00420FDF 8B442404         mov eax,[esp+$04]
00420FE3 8B0490           mov eax,[eax+edx*4]
```

Note that there are <strike>no</strike> less unneeded indirect memory references and reads are properly aligned.

Of course the asm version is slightly better, but the difference between the asm and pascal version should be less than between the two Pascal versions.

This is where I think your performance is wasted.
The misaligned reads eat up a lot of (wasted) cycles on X86.
On other processors the slowdown is even worse.

**Other issues with the code**
Limiting your implementation to strings is a bad thing to do.
What if I want to hash a record?
Do not force binary data into strings.
Strings are a bad fit for binary data.
Just use an untyped parameter and pointers.

**Seed values**
I don't think there is a *correct* seed value. The way I understood it the seed is there so you can chain calls to Murmurhash.
You use the output of the first hash as the seed for the second run.
That way you can feed 2 variables in and get the same output as if you processed those two variables in one go.

Let me know how they perform against your code.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful explanation! Your ASM code is very very fast! Thanks for sharing it! 
PS: I noticed an error in the pascal code... you missed to initialize the "remaining" variable.
Again thank you very much!

Comment: FWIW Integer holds 32 bit pointers fine. Signed or unsigned it doesn't really matter unless range/overflow checking is enabled.

Comment: @Alex, yeah you're welcome. Nice spot on `remaining`